# Achieving FTP/SFTP without 3rd party dll with FtpWebRequest if possible in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to achieve the ftp/sftp through FtpWebRequest class in C# but not succeeded till now.

I dont want to use any 3rd party free or paid dll.

credentials are like

1. hostname = sftp.xyz.com
2. userid   = abc
3. password  = 123

I am able to achieve the ftp with Ip address but unable to acheive sftp for above hostname with credentials.

For sftp I have enabled the EnableSsl property of FtpWebRequest class to true but getting error unable to connect to remote server.

I am able to connect with Filezilla with the same credentials and hostname but not through code.

I observed filezilla, it changes the host name from sftp.xyz.com to sftp://sftp.xyz.com
in textbox and in command line it changes the userid to abc@sftp.xyz.com

I have done the same in code but not succeeded for sftp.

Please need urgent help on this. Thanks in advance.

Below is my code so far:

```
private static void ProcessSFTPFile()
{
    try
    {
        string[] fileList = null;
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        string uri = "ftp://sftp.xyz.com";

        FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(uri));
        ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
        ftpRequest.EnableSsl = true;
        ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("abc@sftp.xyz.com", "123");
        ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
        ftpRequest.Timeout = System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite;

        //ftpRequest.AuthenticationLevel = Security.AuthenticationLevel.MutualAuthRequested;
        //ftpRequest.Proxy = null;
        ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
        ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;

        //Hook a callback to verify the remote certificate 
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);
        //ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string line = reader.ReadLine();
        while (line != null)
        {
            result.Append("ftp://sftp.xyz.com" + line);
            result.Append("\n");
            line = reader.ReadLine();
        }

        if (result.Length != 0)
        {
            // to remove the trailing '\n'
            result.Remove(result.ToString().LastIndexOf('\n'), 1);

            // extracting the array of all ftp file paths
            fileList = result.ToString().Split('\n');
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    if (certificate.Subject.Contains("CN=sftp.xyz.com"))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: ftp with ssl is _ftps_, not sftp. sftp is an entirely different protocol based on ssh.

Comment: And, there's nothing as far as I know for SSH-based protocols in .NET.

Comment: thnks but what should i do i have given the host name starting with sftp and filezilla is also adding sftp before hostname while connecting. please elaborate more with some steps or code.

Comment: Hi @JoachimIsaksson i have basically 2 hostnames given one is sftp.xyz.com and other is ftp.xyz.com what should i do. How can I acheive this in .net

Comment: @pan4321 sftp isn't available in .NET without third party libraries, so if you _really_ don't want to use any third party code, you'll have to do implement it yourself. Otherwise, SharpSSH has worked for me but (most of?) the commercial implementations are more stable.

Answer (score 18):

### UPDATE:

If using [BizTalk, you can work with the SFTP Adapter](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19781.biztalk-server-2013-how-to-use-sftp-adapter.aspx), using the [ESB Toolkit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/biztalk-esbtoolkit.aspx). It has been supported since 2010. One wonders why it didn't make it to the `.Net Framework`

1. [BizTalk Server 2013: Creating Custom Adapter Provider in ESB Toolkit SFTP As an Example](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22035.biztalk-server-2013-creating-custom-adapter-provider-in-esb-toolkit-sftp-as-an-example.aspx)
2. [BizTalk Server 2013: How to use SFTP Adapter](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22035.biztalk-server-2013-creating-custom-adapter-provider-in-esb-toolkit-sftp-as-an-example.aspx)
3. [MSDN Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/dn232420(v=azure.100))

--

Unfortunately, it still requires alot of work to do with just the Framework currently. Placing the `sftp` protocol prefix isnt enough to `make-it-work` Still no built-in, .Net Framework support today, maybe in the future.

**---------------------------------------------------------**

**1) A good library to try out is [SSHNet](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET).**

**---------------------------------------------------------**

It has:

1. a lot more features, including built-in streaming support.
2. an API document
3. a simpler API to code against

Example code from documentation:

**List directory**

```
/// <summary>
/// This sample will list the contents of the current directory.
/// </summary>
public void ListDirectory()
{
    string host            = "";
    string username        = "";
    string password        = "";
    string remoteDirectory = "."; // . always refers to the current directory.
    
    using (var sftp = new SftpClient(host, username, password))
    {
        sftp.Connect();

        var files = sftp.ListDirectory(remoteDirectory);
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(file.FullName);
        }
    }
}
```

**Upload File**

```
/// <summary>
/// This sample will upload a file on your local machine to the remote system.
/// </summary>
public void UploadFile()
{
    string host           = "";
    string username       = "";
    string password       = "";
    string localFileName  = "";
    string remoteFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(localFile);

    using (var sftp = new SftpClient(host, username, password))
    {
        sftp.Connect();

        using (var file = File.OpenRead(localFileName))
        {
            sftp.UploadFile(remoteFileName, file);
        }

        sftp.Disconnect();
    }
}
```

**Download File**

```
/// <summary>
/// This sample will download a file on the remote system to your local machine.
/// </summary>
public void DownloadFile()
{
    string host           = "";
    string username       = "";
    string password       = "";
    string localFileName  = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(localFile);
    string remoteFileName = "";

    using (var sftp = new SftpClient(host, username, password))
    {
        sftp.Connect();

        using (var file = File.OpenWrite(localFileName))
        {
            sftp.DownloadFile(remoteFileName, file);
        }

        sftp.Disconnect();
    }
}
```

**---------------------------------------------------------**

**2) Another alternative library is [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library)**

**---------------------------------------------------------**

With the follwing example:

```
using System;
using WinSCP;
 
class Example
{
    public static int Main()
    {
        try
        {
            // Setup session options
            SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
            {
                Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
                HostName = "example.com",
                UserName = "user",
                Password = "mypassword",
                SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"
            };
 
            using (Session session = new Session())
            {
                // Connect
                session.Open(sessionOptions);
 
                // Upload files
                TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
                transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary;
 
                TransferOperationResult transferResult;
                transferResult = session.PutFiles(@"d:\toupload\*", "/home/user/", false, transferOptions);
 
                // Throw on any error
                transferResult.Check();
 
                // Print results
                foreach (TransferEventArgs transfer in transferResult.Transfers)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Upload of {0} succeeded", transfer.FileName);
                }
            }
 
            return 0;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e);
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

[Found here](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library#csharp) and with [more here](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_examples).

Comment: Syntax for sftp.UploadFile  is not correct here (incorrect parameter order)

Comment: This gist helped me with SSH.NET: https://gist.github.com/DavidDeSloovere/96f3a827b54f20d52bcfda4fe7a16a0b

Answer (score 6):

FTP can be accomplished with .NET alone. There is no built in class for SFTP though. I would recommend taking a look at [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library).

Comment: There's now [.NET library wrapper built around WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) available.

Answer (score 5):

Agreed with Tejs. Just to clarify:

FtpWebRequest with EnableSsl = true means it's ftps, Explicit mode, or in Filezilla wording: "FTPES - FTP over Explicit TLS/SSL, default port 21". You can do this with the built-in .net stuff.

For Implicit ftps (in Filezilla wording "FTPS - FTP over Implicit TLS/SSL, default port 990") you have to use a 3rd party (example ftps.codeplex.com).

For sftp (in Filezilla wording "SSH File Transfer Protocol, default port 22") you also have to use 3rd party (example sshnet.codeplex.com).

As  Joachim Isaksson says, if you can't use 3rd parties, you have to implement it yourself.