# Error unable to connect to remote server when upload file to remote server

Tags: vb.net

I use this code to upload file to server.

```
Dim clsRequest As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = _
                DirectCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create(a), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)
            clsRequest.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, pwd)
            clsRequest.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile

            ' read in file...
            Dim bFile() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pdfPath)

            ' upload file...
            Dim clsStream As System.IO.Stream = _
                clsRequest.GetRequestStream()
            clsStream.Write(bFile, 0, bFile.Length)
            clsStream.Close()
            clsStream.Dispose()
```

But is show error unable to connect to remote server at line   Dim clsStream As System.IO.Stream = _
                    clsRequest.GetRequestStream(). Any wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you pass the right FTP Uri and credentials?

Comment: The error is start at line Dim clsStream As System.IO.Stream = _ clsRequest.GetRequestStream()

Comment: Or how can i check the FTP Uri and credentials?

Comment: Try to open the FTP connection in a capable browser or in a FTP client.

Comment: @Alexander U mean by click CTRL and follow the link? I use this code to check file exists and is working. Dim request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("ftp://ConnDocVault"), FtpWebRequest)
            request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(username, pwd)
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize
            Try
                Dim response As FtpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), FtpWebResponse).

Comment: I see you're using port 22 - are you trying an SFTP connection? That is not supported in .NET. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10657377/achieving-ftp-sftp-without-3rd-party-dll-with-ftpwebrequest-if-possible-in-c-sha

Comment: @Alexander No.I trying to connect to a remote server only.

Comment: Sorry I misread. The ConnDocVault you posted has an additional %22 at the end. Is that part of your actual connection string?

Comment: @Alexander actually it reference to "ftp://11.111.111.11/C$/Vault/Doc/Quotation/Related_Files"

Comment: That does not look like a path an FTP protocol will open. What happens when you open this in Internet Explorer? ftp://11.111.111.11/C$/Vault/Doc/Quotation/Related_Files I presume it won't work. Does 11.111.111.11 actually have a FTP server installed and running?

Comment: @Alexander, Sorry. Is it the FTP refer to a website address? Then ConnDocVault is not refer to a website address. It is a remote server ip address and the drive path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the FTP protocol requires a dedicated FTP server software running on the remote machine. FTP cannot access network drives without it. If you just want to access files on your network, start with this SO question: 
[Copying files to a mapped drive while user is not logged in (scheduled task)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670777/copying-files-to-a-mapped-drive-while-user-is-not-logged-in-scheduled-task)

For security reasons, I strongly recommend a few steps before: 
a) Do not open root shares like C$.
b) Create specific shares on your "remote" server, where you grant access only to users for that specific purpose.

Further reading on FTP: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol